# WPF Redirect in Application_DispatcherUnhandledException

Tags: c#, wpf

I am very new to WPF and I am having a few issues redirecting from the app.xaml.cs Dispatch Unhandled Exception event to a new window.

Basically I am trying to mimic the way a web application deals with errors

1. Error is trapped
2. Error is logged via Elmah
3. Error is emailed via Elmah
4. User is redirected to an error page if the logging/email were successful, if not the error will not be handled

The code I am calling is -

```
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender,
                           System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    ..... Processing Code

    NavigationService svc = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);

    svc.Navigate(new DIEM.WindowsApps.DIEMWindows.ErrorWindow());
}
```

The problem I am having is that when calling NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this), 'this' is null (presumably because App.xaml.cs is not a page, it inherits from Application).

Is there any way around this? Am I doing things completely wrong?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just tried that, still returning null.

Comment: Erm, pass. I really don't know, just picked this up helping someone out. How can I find out?

Comment: Pages. It redirects using a similar method to the one above - NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(name, UriKind.Relative))

Comment: This is from AppWindow - NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this).Navigate(new Uri("/MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

Answer (score 0):

Use the same navigation service you use elsewhere in the application. If it's `AppWindow`, you can save it as a property in the `App` class and access it:

```
public AppWindow()
{
    ((App)Application.Current).AppWindow = this;
}

class App : Application
{
    public AppWindow AppWindow { get; set; }

    private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender,
                               DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        //..... Processing Code

        NavigationService svc = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(AppWindow);

        svc.Navigate(new DIEM.WindowsApps.DIEMWindows.ErrorWindow());
    }

}
```